# Spring mobile redirect 404 error

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm building the mobile version of the site with different layout. I'm using Spring mobile+Thymeleaf. For testing purposes, I'm getting redirected from main site to mobile version. Here's my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app version="2.4"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
         http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd" >


<display-name>Student Accounting site</display-name>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>studentacc</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>studentacc</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/m/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<filter>
    <filter-name>deviceResolverRequestFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.mobile.device.DeviceResolverRequestFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

</webapp>
```

And here's my servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"

       xsi:schemaLocation=
               "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="org.something.webversion"/>

    <mvc:annotation-driven>
        <mvc:argument-resolvers>
            <bean class="org.springframework.mobile.device.site.SitePreferenceWebArgumentResolver" />
            <bean class="org.springframework.mobile.device.DeviceWebArgumentResolver" />
        </mvc:argument-resolvers>
    </mvc:annotation-driven>

    <!--Thymeleaf beans init:START-->
    <bean id="templateResolver"
          class="org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".html"/>
        <property name="templateMode" value="HTML5"/>
        <property name="characterEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="templateEngine"
          class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.SpringTemplateEngine">
        <property name="templateResolver" ref="templateResolver"/>
        <property name="additionalDialects">
            <set>
                <bean class="org.thymeleaf.extras.springsecurity3.dialect.SpringSecurityDialect"/>
            </set>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!--Thymeleaf beans init:END-->     

    <!--Other beans init:START-->
    <mvc:interceptors>
        <!-- Resolve the device which has generated the request -->
        <bean class="org.springframework.mobile.device.DeviceResolverHandlerInterceptor" />

        <!-- User's site preference -->
        <bean class="org.springframework.mobile.device.site.SitePreferenceHandlerInterceptor" />

        <!-- Redirects users to the device specific site -->
        <bean class="org.springframework.mobile.device.switcher.SiteSwitcherHandlerInterceptor" factory-method="urlPath">
            <constructor-arg value="/m" />
        </bean>
    </mvc:interceptors>

    <bean id="liteDeviceDelegatingViewResolver" class="org.springframework.mobile.device.view.LiteDeviceDelegatingViewResolver">
        <constructor-arg>
            <bean class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafViewResolver">
                <property name="templateEngine" ref="templateEngine"/>
                <property name="characterEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
            </bean>
        </constructor-arg>
        <property name="mobilePrefix" value="mobile/" />
        <property name="enableFallback" value="true" />
    </bean>
    <!--Other beans init:END-->

    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/*" location="resources/"/>

</beans>
```

And mine controller:

```
public class MainController {
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MainController.class.getName());

@RequestMapping(value = "/")
public String HelloWorld(Model model,Device device){
    logger.info("Device is "+device);
    if(device.isNormal()){
        return "hello";
    }
    return "index";
}
```

}

Mine webapp folder look like this:
WEB-INF---
          |
         pages---
                |
              mobile---
                       |
                     index.html

So, the redirecting work just fine,I'm getting redirected to mobile version. But page i'm redirected to is non existing(404). I' just can't see the error. Thank you in advance.

Comment: just guess: try replace `/m/*` with `/m/` only

Comment: Nope, that is not the problem.

Comment: wrong guess :) btw: what is the URL you are redirected to? and did you try to enter (assumed) URL manually? my motto is always check the simplest problems first ;)

Comment: I'm redirected to sitename:8080/m/studentacc upon entering with mobile to sitename:8080/studentacc. Doesn't matter if it redirects me or I enter it manually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"rotate" the redirect to url to sitename:8080/studentacc/m" because it is likely that "studentacc" is the name of your application in the application server, and therefore it must be the first part.

From a very short look to the API, I would try to use the [`SiteSwitcherHandlerInterceptor.urlPath(String mobilePath, String rootPath)`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-mobile/docs/current/api/org/springframework/mobile/device/switcher/SiteSwitcherHandlerInterceptor.html#urlPath%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method with the additional parameter for the `rootPath`

```
<bean class="org.springframework.mobile.device.switcher.SiteSwitcherHandlerInterceptor" factory-method="urlPath">
     <constructor-arg value="/m" />
     <constructor-arg value="/studentacc" />
</bean>
```